# algebraic reason that homs to affine schemes factor uniquely through open affine subschemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I notice that an affine open subscheme $X = \operatorname{Spec} R$ of an affine scheme $Y = \operatorname{Spec} S$ has the property that any ring hom $S\rightarrow T$ that factors through $S\rightarrow R \rightarrow T$ does so uniquely (that is the hom from $R$ to $T$ is unique).  In case $X$ is *distinguished* it is clear algebraically why this is the case: the image of $S$ in $R$ somehow generates $R$ if you allow inverses. The same is true if $X$ is not necessarily distinguished but $S$ is integral. But in general, what is the algebraic reason for this uniqueness? Is it generally true that, in the aforementioned sense the image of $S$ in $R$ somehow generates $R$?

Comment: A couple pieces of info that may be helpful: (1) a name for the unique factorization property you observe is that $S\to R$ is a *ring epimorphism*, (2) [this mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20782/ring-theoretic-characterization-of-open-affines) asks which ring maps come from affine open subschemes, and Theorem 1 of Martin Brandenburg's answer is related to your condition of $R$ being generated by $S$ if you allow inverses.